# Stub void method in Spock which populate

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

How can I stub/mock a void method which populates some objects that would be used later.

```
class RequestHelper{
public void populateOrderRequestBody(String product,String quantity,String profile, OrderType orderType){
    orderType.setProduct(product);
    orderType.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
    orderType.setUser(profile.getUserId());
} }

class ServiceClient{
RequestHelper rh;

public void docall(Order order){
    OrderType  orderType = FACTORY.CreateOrderType;
    rh.populateOrderRequestBody(order.getProduct(),order.getQuantity(),order.getProfile(),orderType);
    /**
    * some other code
    **/
}

public setRequestHelper(RequestHelper rh){
    this.rh=rh;
}
public RequestHelper getRequestHelper(){
    return this.rh;
}}
```

Now I want to test ServiceClient class which call RequestHelper to populate orderType object. How to stub the method of RequestHelper class.

Comment: I want to write a test class for ServiceClient class. and I could not decided how to get RequestHelper class as a Mock,Stub or spy.

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case if no verification will be done to `rh` filed you just need a plain `Stub` - just to ensure no `NullPointerException` is thrown when testing the `docall` method. `Mock` will also be sufficient however is more advanced object and using it here is pointless. When it comes to `Spy` it's used to verify invocations on a real (in terms of not being mocked) object. Have a look at the example below - runs smoothly just with `Stub`:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'spec'() {
        given:
        def service = new ServiceClient()    
        service.rh = Mock(RequestHelper)

        when:
        service.doCall(new Order())

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
    }
}

class Order {
    String product
    String quantity
    String profile
}

class OrderType { }

class FACTORY {
    static OrderType CreateOrderType = new OrderType()
}

class RequestHelper {
    public void populateOrderRequestBody(String product, String quantity, String profile, OrderType orderType) {
        orderType.setProduct(product);
        orderType.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
        orderType.setUser(profile.getUserId());
    } 
}

class ServiceClient {
   RequestHelper rh;

   public void doCall(Order order) {
      OrderType  orderType = FACTORY.CreateOrderType;
      rh.populateOrderRequestBody(order.getProduct(), order.getQuantity(), order.getProfile(), orderType);
   }

    public setRequestHelper(RequestHelper rh){
        this.rh=rh;
    }
    public RequestHelper getRequestHelper(){
        return this.rh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: you talk about using `Stub` but you appear to have used `Mock`... is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Opal's answer but using a mock order..

```
class Test extends Specification {
def 'spec'() {
    given:
    def service = new ServiceClient()
    def order = Mock(Order)
    order.getProduct() >> 'product1'
    order.getProfile() >> 'profile1'
    order.getQuantity() >> 3


    service.rh = Mock(RequestHelper)

    when:
    service.doCall(order)

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
    1 * rh.populateOrderRequestBody('product1',3,'profile1',FACTORY.CreateOrderType)
}
}
```

Note that this only works if the CreateOrderType.equals() will return true